# jQuery Validation on 2 Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have the following HTML Code:

```js
// lets monitor the input of values for inputs you can use a class also
  $('input').on('input', function() {
    // added for bit of simplicity or you can directly get valuess
    var step3in1b = $('#step3in1').val();
    var thedate3in2 = $('#step3in2').val();
    if (step3in1b != "" && thedate3in2 != "") {
      // values seems filled remove class  
      $('#step3in1Btn').removeClass('disabled');
    } else {
      // user has emptied some input so add class again.
      $('#step3in1Btn').addClass('disabled');
    }
  });

  
  $(function($){
   $("#step3in1").mask("99/99/9999");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://archive.conductiva.com/files/demos/maskedin/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2-co.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="field text-left">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label class="text-left">Date of Birth</label>
    <input type="text" id="step3in1" name="step3in1b" placeholder="__/__/____" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label class="text-left">Telephone Number</label>
    <input type="tel" id="step3in2" name="thedate3in2" placeholder="+32 000 000 000" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <a href="#" id="step3in1Btn" class="btn disabled">Next Step</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The A Link is being used as a link and has the Class *disabled* so that by default it shows as greyed out (works). When the user fills in both input fields, then the button has class *disabled* removed.

It appears to be correct, but it's not working. Can someone help?

Comment: Your JS code is missing a closing `});` is that a mistake when copying code to the question?

Comment: It's working fine with `bootstrap` css included and after fixing `});`.

Comment: Just a mistake in copy and pasting my code.

I also have the following library which appears to be doing a conflict:

$(function($){ $("#step3in1").mask("99/99/9999", {placeholder: '__/__/____'}); });

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://archive.conductiva.com/files/demos/maskedin/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2-co.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `keyup` or `focus` or `blur` function to check input value after user filled inputs.

```js
$('input').on('keyup blur focus', function() {
    var step3in1b = $('#step3in1').val();
    var thedate3in2 = $('#step3in2').val();
    if (step3in1b != "" && thedate3in2 != "") {
      $('#step3in1Btn').removeClass('disabled');
    } else {
      $('#step3in1Btn').addClass('disabled');
    }
  });
```

```css
.disabled {
    color: gray;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field text-left">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label class="text-left">Date of Birth</label>
    <input type="text" id="step3in1" name="step3in1b" placeholder="__/__/____" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label class="text-left">Telephone Number</label>
    <input type="tel" id="step3in2" name="thedate3in2" placeholder="+32 000 000 000" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <a href="#" id="step3in1Btn" class="btn disabled">Next Step</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This almost works as I require.

I also have the following code to add a Mask:

$(function($){
 $("#step3in1").mask("99/99/9999", {placeholder: '__/__/____'});
});

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://archive.conductiva.com/files/demos/maskedin/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2-co.min.js"></script>

Which is enabling the button on click of the number field.

Can you help?